# Return partial int value when matching two number sets

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I am working with data like the following:

> 8443913000  |  39211900
>
> 8483409000  |  84834029

I want to see if the first 5 numbers or the first 6 numbers match. However, I would like to return the digits instead of returning a text value, i.e. "Same" or "Not Same". Currently I am just using an if statement:

> if(left(A1,5)=left(B1,5),"Same","Not Same")

While I may need to use INDEX/MATCH I am just not sure about the output.

Thank you

Edit: The right column is the master number and the left column is the slave number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just checking for a match, you can use the `LEFT()` in the return:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,5)=LEFT(B1,5),LEFT(A1,5),"Not Same")
```

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried that but thank you for your answer. Worked like a charm.